# Covariates and moderator variables

Tags: interaction, covariance, ancova

I have a 4 * 3 (both the IVs are categorical) factorial design with two covariates (both are continuous) to run ANCOVA. Can I do a moderation analysis?

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at your sample size and see if it is appropriate if you should do a moderation analysis. You are already estimating a large number of terms (your IVs, the interactions between the IVs, and your two covariates). If you are going to include interactions between your IVs and your covariates, you need to:

1. have an appropriate reason grounded in the literature to do so. Including an interaction term because you can is very different from if the literature suggests you should. I can assure you that a good reviewer will want to know the reason that you included a term in your manuscript. And saying "it was there so i did it" is rarely a reason that will convince an editor/reviewer.
2. Do you have the necessary sample size to estimate your model? Even if your model is able to converge, there is a real possibility that you will face an issue of sparsity if you do not have a large enough sample. You must ask yourself, do you really want to make inference on a three-way interaction with a small associated sample size.
3. Finally, be wary of inserting too many spurious interaction terms. It would not be beyond a reviewer to suggest that you are significance hunting. The number of estimated terms in your model is over 20. There is a good chance that one will be spuriously significant just based on pure chance.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing inherent in your problem that prohibits you from doing a moderation analysis.

That doesn't say that it is a good idea to do one. Whether it is a good idea depends on the nature of your data, your sample size, the theory (whether from the literature or from some new theory) and so on.